# Having Problem in making new Partitions

Tags: partitioning

Help me out.
I am unable to make new partition.I installed Ubuntu today.
Attaching a screenshot I hope this will help coz I am new to ubuntu.
And also I dont wanna wipe or format anything.

[image]

Comment: Did you try http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual ?

Comment: Backup your data first, potentially any change to the drive schema could cause data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike NTFS, EXT4 partitions cannot be resized while they are mounted and in use.

**You will have to boot a live USB stick to resize the partition.**

Comment: Little key icons show it is mounted.

Comment: Will it wipe the partition.

Comment: @VinayKharayat That depends on what you tell Gparted to do!